# Could not see "persist.service.adb.enable" value from default.prop of Android device?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I read some guide to get the `persist.service.adb.enable` value, and it said that it belongs to `default.prop` file on device. Its content should be:

```
#
# ADDITIONAL_DEFAULT_PROPERTIES
#
ro.secure=1
ro.debuggable=0
persist.service.adb.enable=0
```

But when i connect device to PC (Linux), try to pull out this file from device (both emulator and Samsung Galaxy Nexus), the content of default.prop file is only:

```
#
# ADDITIONAL_DEFAULT_PROPERTIES
#
ro.secure=1
ro.debuggable=0
persist.sys.usb.config=mass_storage
```

So I could not see `persist.service.adb.enable`. Could anyone tell me why, and how can i got it?

Answer (score 1):

According to the official android documentation, another way to get this value [is to use the `getprop` command](http://developer.android.com/search.html#q=getprop&t=0). (Link takes you to search results for getprop.)

I have not tested this.

I'm assuming you want to also set this value, not just get it? You can use the command line on the phone to do so.  (Disclaimer: I've only tried this in Donut, Froyo, and Gingerbread.)

`setprop persist.service.adb.enable 1`

This is the USB debugging setting; you can also just turn on USB debugging.

Answer (score 1):

In ICS, `persist.service.adb.enable=0` has been replaced by `persist.sys.usb.config=mass_storage`, so you if you want to eanble ADB, you can `setprop persist.sys.usb.config=mass_storage,adb`